# Prevent PopupWindow from opening multiple windows

Tags: dynamic

`PopupWindow` objects can be clicked multiple times, opening multiple popup windows for the same object. How can I prevent this?

A bit more detail: I have an application which displays a graphic. The user can click on elements of the graphic to call up an information panel about that element using `PopupWindow`. The user might have several of these popups open at once. To prevent confusion, I would like to make sure that the user cannot open more than one popup per object. I can't see a straightforward approach to doing this, so I'm hoping for some ideas from this fine community.

Example code:

```
DynamicModule[{col = ConstantArray[Blue, 5]},
 Graphics[{Table[With[{i = i},
     PopupWindow[
      Dynamic[
       col[[i]] = If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Blue];
       {Dynamic@col[[i]], Disk[{i, 0}, 0.5]}],
      Dynamic[
       col[[i]] = If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Blue];
       Framed[Style["Disk " <> ToString[i], White, 20], 
        FrameMargins -> 80, Background -> Dynamic@col[[i]]]], 
      WindowSize -> 280]
     ], {i, 5}]}]]
```

*Here I have clicked on disk 4 twice, opening a duplicate of the information window. I want to prevent that:*

[image]

Comment: Only idea I have is: You could give each `PopupWindow` title and then check every `Notebooks[]` every second or so to close duplicates?

Comment: You can define an index list for windows e.g. from 1 to 5. Before opening a window check if the index is still there in the list then remove the index and open the window else do nothing.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with `PopoupWindow[]`, because once issued it will ever bring up a window with the specified contents. You can, however, create a notebook if it hasn't been created yet. You may use ``FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListWindows"]]`` to check the currently active notebooks.

Comment: @belisarius, thanks. I'm not clear on what your code snippet gives that `Notebooks[]` doesn't?

Comment: For me, any `PopupWindow` blocks evaluation (editing is okay) within any other notebooks until it is dismissed. Is that normal behavior?

Comment: @YvesKlett, yes that's normal. You can change the behaviour with `WindowFloating->False`.

Comment: @Rojo, forgetfulness! Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: And thanks for answering. You made me come back to this and realise I had downvoted your answer instead of upvoting!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `PopupWindow` object is nothing more than a `Button` with a `CreateDocument` action:

```
PopupWindow[a, b] // InputForm

(* Button[a, CreateDocument[Internal`PopupWindowNotebook[b]], 
Appearance -> None, BaseStyle -> {}, DefaultBaseStyle -> {}] *)
```

Since `CreateDocument` returns a notebook object which can be assigned to a symbol, it is simple to check if there is an already open popup window. By inserting this check into the `Button` code, the desired behaviour is obtained:

```
singlePopup[pw_] := With[{p = Unique["popup"]},
  pw /. Button[a_, b_, c___] :>
    Button[a, If[! ValueQ[p] || Options[p] == $Failed, p = b], c]]

(* e.g. *) PopupWindow["Click here", "You clicked!"] // singlePopup
```

Comment: Very nice, a big +1

Comment: V11.3  appears to have broken this, so after poping up and then closing, you can no longer popup again.

Comment: According to Wolfram support this is a bug and will be fixed in a future release.  Options[NotebookObject["bad"]]  will return an empty List, {}, instead of \$Failed. Support provided a workaround:      Add Options[p] == {} to your If statement:
singlePopup[pw_] := 
 With[{p = Unique["popup"]}, pw /. Button[a_, b_, c___] :> Button[a, If[! ValueQ[p] || Options[p] == {} || Options[p] == $Failed, p = b], c]]

Comment: @DrBubbles, thanks for the update. I actually ran across this today and changed `Options` to `NotebookInformation` which also worked.